# How to monitor status of actionmailer deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rails-activejob

## TL;DR

How to keep track of queued mails which are enqueued by `deliver_later`, along with their delivery state?

## Details

I want to send a bunch of emails async using `deliver_later` from action mailer. It works so far as in mails are sent async and `wait:` works as expected. So far so good.

I now want to provide some status info about the status of the sent mails. I.e. a simple string like `x/y mails sent` which I can query via http or whatever later on (which is **not** a concern of this question!). My expectation was that I can easily access a job queue or something like that where I can then register a callback like in `after_action` but apparently there is no such thing and it looks like I need to handcraft that using said callbacks but I cannot find a single resource even mentioning the topic 'delivery state'. It appears as if nobody in the world is interested if and when `deliver_later`ed mails are actually sent oO? The closest thing I could found was how to check for this for the purpose of unit tests, but this is definitely not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

There is no datastore (aside from your background job system of choice) that stores information about the completeness or status of your async delivery. However, you can observe the delivery of mail with the Rails Observer pattern. If you'd like to track attempts and status of mail deliveries, I would add a table to your database for each delivery.

#### Tracking that a mailer method was called to create a delivery:

You could add an `before_action` to your mailer that writes a database record for the mail message that was called. Give your message a UUID here so you can find it later in the database. The UUID could be added to your message headers.

#### Tracking that a mailer delivered a message (later):

You can add an observer to your mailer (or all mailers) with `register_observer`. The Observer class must implement `self.delivered_email(message)` and that method will be called after an email has been delivered. At that point you could find your database record and write a timestamp on it to mark it as "sent".

Here's an example of what that might look like:

**This is untested code, it may not work exactly as written**

```
# your mailer class
class NotifierMailer < ApplicationMailer
  after_action :record_delivery

  private

  def record_delivery
    # create an identifier for this mail message and add it 
    # to the headers of the mail message
    headers['X-Delivery-Id'] = SecureRandom.uuid
    # write a database record to track that this email is to be sent
    MailDelivery.create(uuid: headers['X-Delivery-Id'])
  end
end

# an observer class
class MailDeliveryObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    delivery = MailDelivery.find_by(uuid: message.header['X-Delivery-Id'])
    delivery&.touch(:sent_at)
  end
end

# in application.rb
# NotifierMailer can be any mailer
NotifierMailer.register_observer(MailDeliveryObserver)
```

[Here's an article that explains a little more about observers](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mail-interceptors-and-observers)

[And some current Rails docs on observers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Observing+and+Intercepting+Mails)

Comment: Whats the point in adding the identifier to the mail headers? Is it simply to map the  actual mail a person has received with the entry in the database?

Comment: This creates 2 entries in the database for each email as the callback is apparently called twice. A database log is nice and stuff but what I want is a boolean that tells me wether or not that mail (by "that" I mean the mail object I have stored in memory before) was successfully sent or not and thats it. It seems super hard to do this for no reason with actionmailer/actionjob unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I mean `delivered_email` is the hook for an observer trying to tell if "mail was successfully sent or not", but once you tell a background job to do that (`deliver_later`) you've got to store that unit of "work" in a distributed fashion. Depending on your Email Service Provider, you can usually also receive webhooks from your ESP when mail was delivered. I don't think Amazon SES does this. Otherwise your background job that's sending the email has to be the one to write "successfully sent" to a distributed store somewhere.

Comment: See the problem is ActionMailer creates 2 different Mail objects which leads to two delivery-ids stored in the databases where only one will get „sent“ as the other was never meant to be sent. As the header gets deleted when the new mail object is created the second time there’s no way to tell which of the dB records refers to the same message of that second mail object. So your approach does not work at all regarding identifying sent mails. It’s only good to tell wether or not emails where sent but not to check if a certain email that was called delivered_later on got send.

Comment: besides that ,the solution is somewhat overengineered. i can see a "Job ID" . which is generated by activejob in the logs. I can see "performing" . as well as "performed" log-messages which matching "Job ID"s. it must be possible to craft some simple in-memory observer for this instead of relying on a database.

Comment: Good luck. Sounds like you know what to do.

Comment: The id must be passed as a parameter to the call to the action mailer method e.g. `ActionMailer.with(delivery_id: SecureRandom.uuid)`. This way every subsequently created `Mail` object will get the same id passed as a param. With that the message can be delivered in `delivered_mail`. If messing around with the mail object otherwise several IDs will be generated without having a way to tell which one of those is refering to a duplicated object.

Comment: > This creates 2 entries in the database for each email.

I have moved creating the AR record to the interceptor and this fixed the issue with 2 records

Comment: FYI : in the observer the correct object is `message.header['X-Delivery-Id']` (singular `header`).

Comment: @maxigs thank you. I've updated the answer to reflect this.